# Qt: display qgraphicsitem in a widget

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I got a QGraphicsScene that contains QGraphicsItems. On clicking such an item I open a dialog. I now want the item to be displayed in an area of the dialog.

I tried a QGraphicsView (in the dialog) and "pointed" it to the item which works allmost perfectly. The problem is, that it is possible to click the item in the dialog which would open a new dialog.

So my question: is there a easy way to tell QGraphicsView to ignore any input events? If not, is there a easy way to display a QGraphicsItem within a widget?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not the solution. If I install an eventFilter for the QGraphicsView I get the Events 10, 11, 24, 25 and more but NOT QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick (158) or GraphicsSceneWheel (168). These events seem to be directly forwarded to the QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 1):

I am feeling so stupid...

`QGraphicsView::setInteractive(false)` did the trick.
I am still able to move the icon with the mouse wheel but this can probably be avoided by restricting the scene rect with setSceneRect()

Answer (score 0):

You can install an event filter, on the QGraphicsView, which ignores input events. The Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) states:

> In your reimplementation of this function, if you want to filter the event out, i.e. stop it being handled further, return true; otherwise return false.